# Stopping a forEach on prop change (ReactJS, Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

So I'm not sure of the most effective way to do this, or if I'm even approaching it in the right way.

I have an application that grabs a long array of image URLs (800+) while `props.loading = true`, and loads these images into another array. Then, when I play the slideshow generated by these images, I'm trying to figure out how to stop image loading inside the forEach. Here's my snippet for the images:

```
getImages = () => {
     this.props.links.forEach(url => {
         const img = document.createElement('img');
         img.src = url;
         img.onload = () => {
              store.dispatch(addImage(img));
         } 
     })
}
```

Is there some way to use `componentDidUpdate` or another approach to cut off the forEach when `this.props.loading = true`? My main concern is performance - without waiting for all images to load, the resulting slideshow lags heavily, but plays smoothly with zero issues after everything is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In componentDidUpdate you can use `prevProps` to compare with `this.props`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.links.length === this.props.links.length) {
    // links array length did not change
  }
}
```

This should allow you to check and only call `getImages` if props did not update.

Comment: Apologies, maybe I was asking for the wrong thing. I preload all urls (async), then start the image loader. I want to be able to kill the image loader forEach at will if `this.props.loading = false`. Already using what you posted to trigger the url preloader!

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure how you could stop it - cDU runs when props change, so a simple conditional check would "restart" cDU (I believe). The greater issue to me seems to be that if you were to "stop" it, you're potentially running dispatch more times than necessary, but I might be missing what your code does or is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you really need all these images loaded into your store on each render? Your slowdown is most likely caused by the amount of actions you are dispatching every time the component renders. Could you share the rest of the component code and your reducer code or link the repo? Without seeing the rest of the code base there are a few things I can think of that you can try.

Also know componentDidUpdate() only runs after the render function.

- You could try to lazy load the images in chunks to the gallery using [react-lazy-load](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load) or the new React Suspense API as opposed to loading the images in the forEach. This way your gallery won't have all the upfront logic to compute. Of course, this may not work for your use case if you actually do need all those images in the store.
- You could try to use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to implement some logic if the component should actually reconcile and re-render, but this still won't account for the initial load just the subsequent loads. You would also need to make sure you aren't dispatch actions for images that are already in the store.

  ```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
      if(this.props.loading && !nextProps.loading){
          return true
      } else {
          return false
      }
  }
  ```